# No puedo crear proyecto en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Instalé rails desde http://railsinstaller.org/en

Luego de instalarlo quise crear un proyecto con el comando

```
C:\Sites>rails new blog
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el comando la respuesta es la siguiente:

> No se puede encontrar la ruta.

Pueden darme algún indicio de lo que podría ser?..... Es primera vez que lo instalo.

Comment: No conozco la instalación de rails en windows, pero revisa en que carpeta quedaron instalados los ejecutables de ruby/rails y agrégalos a tu [variable de entorno PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general no es recomendable utilizar *rails* en Windows ya que genera muchos problemas (muchas gemas importantes simplemente no funcionan bien), lo recomendable sería que utilices una distro GNU/Linux o si utilizas Windows 10, utilizar el subsistema Windows para que utilice *bash*. Ahora, con el problema que se te presenta, es debido a que no tienes *rails* agregado al *PATH*, tienes que modificar las variables de entorno.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, finalmente tuve que actualizar el bundler. por que al momento de la instalación la gema no estaba actualizada. Gracias.